# Is Rails running in the current Ruby process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The Ruby mixin module I'm writing would be useful for both vanilla Ruby and Rails.  What's the best practice for determining at run-time whether Rails is loaded?  Is it possible to get the version number as well?

In `script/console` for a Rails 2.3.4 project `ENV.has_key?("RAILS_ENV")` is true and it's false in my Ruby 1.8.7 interpreter.  Is there a more reliable way to tell for all versions of Rails or is this pretty safe?

As for getting the Rails version in the current process, I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if one of the Rails modules is defined with

```
defined?(Rails)
```

Additionally, you can get the version with

```
Rails.version
```